# What to do when two algorithms perform better on different set of classes while doing multi-class classification?

Tags: classification, multiclass-classification, hyperparameter-tuning

If an algorithm X performed better on a set of classes U and another algorithm Y works better on set of classes V where U and V don's share any class, what improvements can be done from a data scientist view?

Also, please highlight the case where U and V share few classes.

Comment: I guess the last word of your question should be *features* not *classes*. About your task it highly depends on your algorithm but it is clear that you have to use confusion matrix for evaluation. Moreover, you have to use error analysis techniques.

Comment: Nope, I meant to use 'classes' only. e.g. algorithm x gives better accuracy in classifying classes 'c1, c2, c3' but works poor for 'c3, c4, c5'. Similarly, algorithm y works for 'c3, c4, c5' but works poorly for 'c1, c2, c3'. Hope, it clarifies the doubt.

Comment: Are you familiar with error analysis?

Comment: Nope. Is it related to the question I asked?

Comment: https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/lecture/x62iE/error-analysis

Comment: using both and averaging the results (a.k.a. ensembling) is a too easy reply?

Comment: Depends on how easy it is to create a classifier to distinguish whether a new data point belongs to U or V